# how can I set Roboto Slab to italic using fontspec

Tags: fontspec

I am having the weird behaviour, that I cannot get a given font to be italic. Bold is no problem, but italic is.

```
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Roboto Slab}[
        Ligatures={TeX},
        %ItalicFont=Roboto Slab Light, % I can set another font, but seem not to be able to find THIS font in italic.
]
```

when I now do

```
\textsl{text} ... or ... \itshape mytext
```

nothing happens.

How do I get the font to italic.

Comment: There is no italic Roboto Slab, cf. https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Slab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Roboto Slab** has no italic font, but you can use fontspec's fake slant feature:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Roboto Slab}[
  AutoFakeSlant=0.2,      
  Ligatures={TeX},
]

\begin{document}
  \textsl{text} ... or ... \itshape mytext
\end{document}
```

[image]

The result is really ugly. Better use **Roboto** or **Roboto Condensed** instead...